# Is it possible to instantiate a structure (tuple/list) knowing its type (Tuple/List)?

Tags: python, list, tuples, extract

I'm currently developing python code to mock a certain C library. I have access to the library functions and docstrings thanks to pybind. The task is to mock the return of these functions.

##### The situation

So far, I can successfully read any function output using regex. Now, I need to evaluate the type of this output, get what's inside of this type and either instantiate it to a known value or fill it with an object. Here's an example of what I'm trying to explain:

```
docstring = parse(getattr(MyClass, the_method_I_want_to_mock).__doc__)

# The regex will read from -> to the end of the output hinting
method_type_search = re.search(r"(?<=-> ).+(?=)", docstring.short_description)

# If the regex finds something, evaluate the output
evaluated_method = eval(method_type_search.group(0))
```

At this point, an `evaluated_method` value would evaluate to something like : `typing.Tuple[int, int]`

##### The problem

###### Here's what I'm seeking to do:

1. Extract the type of the return
2. Extract what's inside (if, for example, I'm dealing with a tuple/list)
3. Create an instantiated structure with step 1) and 2). For example: `typing.Tuple[int, int]` would yield `(0, 0)` and `typing.List[float, user_class]` would yield `[0.0, user_class()]`

###### Here's what I have done so far:

```py
# eval_method is in the form of `typing.Tuple[int, int]` like aforementioned
def test_evaluate_types(eval_method):
    #This is the dictionary I plan on using to turn a type (ex: int) into its value (ex: 0). 
    #If any output requires an instantiated object (ex: typing.Tuple[user_class, int],
    #I'll need to instantiate the user_class and turn the int into 0.
    evaluate_dict: dict = { 
        int: 0,
        List[int]: [0, 1, 2]
    }
    out = []
    # checks if there is a structure or if its only one type (tuple[int, int] vs int)
    try:
        eval_method_type = eval_method._name
    except AttributeError:
        # if it's a simple type, return its value
        return evaluate_dict[eval_method]

    # This fetches what's inside a structure (ex: [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>])
    eval_method_output = eval_method.__args__
    # parsing what is inside the structure and instanciating it.
    for idx, output in enumerate(eval_method_output):
        out.append(evaluate_dict[output])

#This WOULD casts the list into whatever structure was found earlier.
#It doesn't work and I'm stuck here.
return eval(eval_method_type + f"({out})")
```

I feel like I'm maybe complicating my issue, but can't seem to find a function/way to easily convert ANY type (even user type) into a chosen output like stated above.

Comment: The `type()` function returns the class of an input object. Note that `typing.Tuple()` is _not_ the same as the `tuple` class, but the former is a representation of the latter useful mainly for type annotations.  Python doesn't require the type annotations to be complete (or accurate).
I don't think I understand your problem: Are you trying to recognize a type from its string representation? Are you trying to recognize the type of an existing object?

Comment: We're trying to evaluate a type from its string annotation representation ( Tuple[int, int] to tuple(int, int) )

Comment: with [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) you may access to the signature

Comment: I've tried many of inspect's methods but none are offering me what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `__origin__` dunder can be used to get the necessary `tuple`. So then, when I have the string `Tuple[int, int]`, I then call an `eval()` on it, which gives me `typing.Tuple[int, int]`. Using the dunder `__origin__` on the eval's result, I then get the `tuple` I was looking for and instantiate it directly.

```
string_to_eval: str = "Tuple[int, int]"
string_eval = eval(string_to_eval)  # Yields the aforementionned typing.Tuple[int, int]
tuple_result = string_eval.__origin__()  # Yields 'tuple'
```